# Does Google Chrome support text-track cues?

Tags: javascript

I have a website that uses javascript subtitles on videos.  Sometimes users may have old browsers, so I have a function that checks whether the browser can handle text-track cues (subtitles).  Here it is:

```
function supportsCues() {
    var cue0;

    try {
        cue0 = new TextTrackCue(2, 4, 'just testing support cues');
        return (true);
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("supportsCues err is " + err); // !!!!
        return (false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This function tells me that in Chrome, I have an 'illegal constructor' and it returns false.

I would think that Chrome would support this feature.
So I must be doing something wrong. 
But what?
Thanks

Comment: This isn't something I have ever used but after a quick search of the docs it looks like you should be creating a VTTCue, rather than a TextTrackCue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VTTCue . Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zjprahkj/1/

Comment: This thread: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/YJ4SY6WHxso seems to confirm that the `TextTrackCue` constructor was removed from the spec.